# Is there a way combine a specific number of chars from fgetc?

Tags: c

I have found some information about strcat and experimented with it but it doesn't work the way i expected for example :

```
char a = 'a', b = 'b';
strcat(a,b);
printf("%c", a);
```

this will produce an error "initialization of 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast". Is there a way to unite chars until the wanted word is complete and store it in 1 variable? Or am i going completely wrong about this. The purpose of the code is to read an xml file and build a tree with the tags.
Any help is or advice is very much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int count = 0;
    char c, word;
    FILE *file = fopen("example.xml", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    do {
        c = fgetc(file);

        if (c == '<') {
            count = 1;
        }
        if (c == '>') {
            count = 0;
            printf(">");
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            printf("%c", c);
            
        }
        if (feof(file)){
            break ;
        }   
    } while(1);

    fclose(file);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `strcat` doesn't take 2 chars as input, but rather, 2 strings (char arrays).

Comment: A "word" has to be a `char` array (with a null-terminator at the end to be a proper string). So obviously you can't store that into a single `char`

Comment: And `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`. This is in order to let the caller know that the end of file has been reached (in which case, function `fgetc` returns `EOF`, which is an `int` size value).

Comment: So to begin with, you need to change `char c` to `int c`, and if `c != EOF`, then you can proceed with printing `(char)c`.

Comment: Alright, i did not know that kind of detail, i added those changes to my code.

Comment: But using `c != EOF` will only let me print the first character of the file so it has to be `c == EOF` in this instance.

Comment: It is quite common to put the assignment to `c` (of type `int`) within the `while` condition along with the check for `EOF` like this: `while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)` `{` `/* do stuff with c */` `}`. There is no need for the call to `feof`. Some coding standards do not allow this usage though.

Comment: @IanAbbott thank u that actually makes the code look more clean.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between `'a'` and `"a"`.  This works:`char a[32] = "a"; char *b="c"; strcat(a, b);`, but be aware that you need to keep track of the size and not allow the `strcat` to overflow the buffer.  `strncat` and `strlcat` can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but you could try something like the following, which will print every <tag>, i.e., every string in the file between <...>'s , and will also accumulate them in an array of strings called tags[]. And note that you'd might want to add checks that avoid going over the 99 chars/tag and 999 tags total. But if this isn't anything like what you're actually trying to do, maybe clarify the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    int ntags=0, ichar=0,nchars=0;
    char c='\000', tags[999][99];
    FILE *file = fopen("example.xml","r");
    if (file==NULL) return(0);
    while((ichar=fgetc(file))!=EOF) {
        c = (char)ichar;
        if (nchars==0 && c!='<') continue;
        tags[ntags][nchars++] = c;
        if (c=='>') {
          tags[ntags][nchars] = '\000';
          printf("tag#%d = %s\n",ntags+1,tags[ntags]);
          nchars=0; ntags++; }
        }
     /* do you now want to do anything with your tags[] ??? */ 
     fclose(file);
     return(0);
     }
```

Comment: the final goal is to take these tags and use them in a n-ary tree, i have no directions on how to do it so im just going in blind trying things and keeping what sticks :/ , i know how trees work and how to implement one but doing it with strings is so confusing .

Comment: `tags[ntags][nchars++] = c` -> `error: expected ‘;’ before ‘if’`. Additionally, on well formed XML, this will infinitely loop on EOF; the predicate `nchars == 0 && c != '<'` will always be true at that point.

Comment: @Dr.Hunter Yeah, I kind of got that from _"The purpose of the code is to read an xml file and build a tree with the tags"_ in your original question. But the majority of the question, including your sample code, seemed to be about character and string manipulation. So I just tried to illustrate how you might want to approach that kind of thing. The tree stuff would involve much more logic and code, determining how the tags are nested, etc. You might, in principle, determine that from the sequence of tags accumulated in the tags[] array, but that's likely too naive an approach.

Comment: @Oka Thanks for pointing out the now-corrected little syntax error and EOF check. I didn't really think much about any of it, just wanted to illustrate a little character- and string-handling stuff for the op, based on what I interpreted as the primary purpose of his question.

Comment: @eigengrau yea i have been thinking all day yesterday and this morning and i came up with something like this 

`link parse(){
char t = a[i++];

link result = createnode(t, NULL, NULL);
    if ((t == '<') || (t == '>')) { 
        result->left = parse();
        result->right = parse(); 
    }
    return result;
}`
 i think im going in the right direction but im stuck again, anyway i thank u for ur help, that string manipulation example will certainly come handy some day so im keeping it saved. Eh the format is messed up sorry for that.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use a function, those parameters are char *

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
```

but you gave strcat a char but it wants a char*

```
int main()
{
    char str1[20] = "this";
    char str2[] = "is";

     strcat(str1, str2);

     printf("%s", str1);

return 0;

}
```

this is the way i thinkt you want it

Comment: thanks for the tip i forgot it